# How to split set of vertices with Boost Graph?

Tags: c++, graph, boost, parallel-processing

I'm writing some algorithm in C++ for parallel **graph coloring** using **Boost Graph** and **adjacency_list**.
I'm working with very big graph (the smallest has 32K vertices).

What I'm trying to do is to take the whole set of vertices, split them in parts and assign each part to a different thread and work in parallel, but I'm struggling with some passages.

The basic idea what this:

```
int step = g.m_vertices.size()/4;
int min = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    // call the function
}
```

And the function I call inside is something like that

```
for (vp = vertices(g); vp.first != vp.second; ++vp.first) {
    cout << *vp.first << endl;
}
```

So I have two questions:

1. `g.m_vertices.size()/4;` is the right solutions? If initially I have 10 vertices, then I remove some vertex in the middle (e.g. 4), only 6 vertices left (so this is the new size) but the index of the vertices go *from 0 to 5* or *from 0 to 9*?
2. How can pass only a subset of vertices to vp instead of passing `vertices(g)`?

Comment: Is this a general problem of parallel for_each algorithm? If yes, have you considered using `std::for_each` with `std::execution::par` execution policy?

Comment: @smitsyn Yes I did. I'm searching some more efficient solution (if it isn't not too hard to implement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> g.m_vertices.size()/4; is the right solutions?

That depends ONLY on your requirements.

> If initially I have 10 vertices, then I remove some vertex in the middle (e.g. 4), only 6 vertices left (so this is the new size) but the index of the vertices go from 0 to 5 or from 0 to 9?

That depends on your graph model. You don't specify the type of your graph (I know, you *do* say which template, but not the template parameters). Assuming `vecS` for the Vertex container selector, then yes, after 4 removals, the vertex descriptors (and index) will be [0,6).

> How can pass only a subset of vertices to vp instead of passing vertices(g)

Many ways.

1. you can `std::for_each` with a parallel execution policy
2. you can use openmp to create a parallel section from the plain loop
3. you can use `filtered_graph` adapter to create 4 "views" of the underlying graph and operate on those
4. you can use [PBGL](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/graph_parallel/doc/html/index.html) which is actually created for dealing with huge graphs. This has the added benefit that it works with threading/interprocess/inter-host communication, can coordinate algorithms across segments etc.
5. you can use `sub_graph`s; this is mainly (only) interesting if the way your graphs get built have a natural segmentation

None of the solutions are trivial. But, here's naive demo using `filtered_graph`:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/dnhT5aozf)**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/filtered_graph.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/random.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

using G = boost::adjacency_list<>;
using V = G::vertex_descriptor;

G make_graph() {
    G g;
    std::mt19937 prng(std::random_device{}());
    generate_random_graph(g, 32 * 1024 - (prng() % 37), 64 * 1024, prng);
    return g;
}

template <int NSegments, int Segment> struct SegmentVertices {
    std::hash<V> _h;
    bool operator()(V vd) const { return (_h(vd) % NSegments) == Segment; }
};

template <int N>
using Quart = boost::filtered_graph<G, boost::keep_all, SegmentVertices<4, N>>;

template <typename Graph>
void the_function(Graph const& g, std::string_view name)
{
    std::cout << name << " " << size(boost::make_iterator_range(vertices(g)))
            << " vertices\n";
}

int main()
{
    G g = make_graph();
    the_function(g, "full graph");

    Quart<0> f0(g, {}, {});
    Quart<1> f1(g, {}, {});
    Quart<2> f2(g, {}, {});
    Quart<3> f3(g, {}, {});

    the_function(f0, "f0");
    the_function(f1, "f1");
    the_function(f2, "f2");
    the_function(f3, "f3");
}
```

Printing e.g.

```
full graph 32766 vertices
f0 8192 vertices
f1 8192 vertices
f2 8191 vertices
f3 8191 vertices
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm using vecS but I'm not understanding completely how it works, I have to study it better. 
For the second answer I think I'm trying to use filtered_graph adapter and see if it works properly in my project.